# Find value stored in IE object in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have declared an object named `IE` in my VBA code.

`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

Sometimes user may close the browser linked to `IE` object. How can i write code to find if the browser is closed or open?

As shown in below image, software shows `Internet Explorer` when i place cursor on `IE` object during run time. Can this value be used to determine if browser is closed or open? If not, any other way?

[image]

Comment: The first code is VBA and then 2nd VB.Net? Can you clear the confusion please? Have you tried `GetObject()`?

Comment: Both are vba only. Second screen shot is taken using view macro option in excel. I will try getobject().

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` in Excel?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I don't think VB.Net would work with the space before ` (` but you can add references to few .Net libraries in VBA

Comment: @Slai: Yes you can add reference to .Net Libraries but that will not let you see it's code :) The second code is vb.net and not vba

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class to capture the Internet Explorer events using WithEvents.  You'll need to set a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents IE As InternetExplorer

Private Sub IE_OnQuit()

End Sub

Private Sub IE_OnVisible(ByVal Visible As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object is closed, then accessing some of it's members should give you an error.

```
Dim isOpen As Boolean ' False by default
On Error Resume Next
If IE.HWND > 0 Then isOpen = True
On Error Goto 0
```